# Why doesn't my MassTransit Consumer consume a message that exists in AzureServiceBus?

Tags: masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

We're using MassTransit to build microservices using Azure ServiceBus. Up until now we've only used topics (as opposed to queues), since (I guess) we had an easier time getting topics up and running.

I would like to use queues, but can't seem to get it to work. I managed to Send a message - no problem there, and I can see the message in the Azure ServiceBus Explorer, but I just can't seem to make my Consumer eat the message. The same consumer had no problem eating the message when we Subscribed to a topic.

This is how I try to set up the consumer:

```
services.AddMassTransit(c =>
{
   c.AddConsumer<MyConsumer>();
   c.UsingAzureServiceBus((context,cfg) =>
   {
      cfg.Host(connectionString, host => { host.OperationTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0,0,60); });
      cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("super-queue", e =>
      {
          e.ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>(context);
          e.RequiresSession = true;             
      });

      // ...other configs
   });
});

services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

And this is what the message looks like in Azure ServiceBus Explorer

```
{
  "messageId": "00010000-0faa-0009-8bac-08d8f9a4cd7c",
  "conversationId": "00010000-0faa-0009-0077-08d8f9a4cd82",
  "sourceAddress": "sb://slvstmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/IT003477_iisexpress_bus_yyyoyyyxieyy19rjbdcxujf6nr?autodelete=300",
  "destinationAddress": "sb://slvstmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/super-queue",
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:SLV.MassTransit.Meddelanden:IAnsokanInkommen"
  ],
  "message": {
    "korrelationsId": "a5cd9107-fb75-4b4a-a41e-ad729834d4d2",
    "ursprung": "Samtjänsten"
  },
  "sentTime": "2021-04-07T09:09:09.0369452Z",
  "headers": {
    "MT-Activity-Id": "00-978c69d24cc6e94798a901645e370f81-b5b1e47ba0c16e4b-00"
  },
  "host": {
    "machineName": "IT003477",
    "processName": "iisexpress",
    "processId": 54288,
    "assembly": "SLV.Samtjänst-API",
    "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "frameworkVersion": "5.0.1",
    "massTransitVersion": "7.1.4.0",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0"
  }
}
```

And this is what the consumer looks like

```
public class MyConsumer: IConsumer<IAnsokanInkommen>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IAnsokanInkommen> context)
    {
        Log.Information("Got it!");
    }
}
```

PS - IAnsokanInkommen is an interface, in a shared nuget

Comment: What I see looks correct, not sure why it wouldn't consume the message. Assuming the namespaces and the queue names are the same, it should. Any detail if you turn on debug logs for MassTransit?

Comment: Strange error - when we added a New consumer (new name and everything) it started to work.

I've just now gotten logging to the console working, and am trying to add 
e.StateMachineSaga(new AnsökanInkommenSaga(), MessageSessionSagaRepository.Create<AnsokanInkommenTillstand>());
(just below e.ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>(context);)

This gets me: 
[15:27:51 DBG] Endpoint Faulted: "sb://slvstmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/super-queue"

Any tips on that, while we're at it? :)

Comment: PS - adding the StateMachineSaga in this way worked fine when we Subscribed to a Publish, instead of Receiving a Send

Comment: no, but check [the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/session.html#container-integration) to configure your saga correctly.

Comment: The saga works fine, as long as we add it in a SubscribeEndpoint - will have a look at the docs, to see if there is an alternative way to add it that makes it work. -Thank you for your amazing work on MassTransit!